# How To Convert Flatten Table in BigQuery in to GA4 Nested table structure

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, nested, google-analytics-4

I was able to nest event category values, however, with in that i was unable to create key, value pairs for event action and event label  as an array like GA4 raw sessions table structure

I was able to create till this step: https://prnt.sc/3FhZgd7IOmVV
My end goal is to make event action label in this fashion: https://prnt.sc/pT5AOhL7q9S8

For example: I have the below flatten table, how do I make in the above format.

```
with test as (

select 123 cid, "sports" ec, "load" ea, "module" el union all
select 123,"marquee","load","home" union all
select 125,"bet_add","sports","football" union all
select 126, "bet_place","games","tennis" 
)
select cid, array_agg(struct(ec,ea,el)) as events from test group by 1
```

For example: I have created the below flatten table, how do I make in the above format.

```
with test as (

select 123 cid, "sports" ec, "load" ea, "module" el union all
select 123,"marquee","load","home" union all
select 125,"bet_add","sports","football" union all
select 126, "bet_place","games","tennis" 
)
select cid, array_agg(struct(ec,ea,el)) as events from test group by 1
```